# Internet in Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012-r2

I use `Virtual box` from `Oracle`.

I have created an `Ubuntu` machine. The real environment of system is windows server 2012 r2 and I log in remotely.

I try to open firefox in Ubuntu VM but I don't have any internet connection. What can I do to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your virtual box machine settings go to network and enable a NAT adapter or any other kind of virtual network will fit your needs. Also, make sure that in the host server you have a virtual network connection (networking in control panel). If not, there may be a problem with your virtual box installation.